# Average using dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, average

I am trying to calculate the average using dictionaries once I have collated the input required. Can you please help? The error message I get is

```
 line 21, in <module> average = 
 sum(student_info[student_name]/len(student_info))TypeError: 'float' object 
 is not iterable"
```

The code is

```
login="teacher"
password="school"

usrnm=input("Please enter your username: ")
pw=input("Please enter your password: ")

if (usrnm==login) and (pw==password):
   print("==Welcome to the Mathematics Score Entry Program==")
   print("Do you want to enter the students score? Yes/No: ")
   option = input()
   option = option.title()
   student_info = {}
   while (option != "No"):
     student_name = input("Name :")
     student_info[student_name] = {}
     score = int(input("Please enter score: "))
     student_info[student_name] = score
     print("Do you want to enter the students score? Yes/No: ")
     option = input()
     option = option.title()
average = sum(student_info[student_name]/len(student_info))
print ("The average score is ", average)
else:
    print("No way, Jose!")
```

Comment: What do you think you're summing *over*? At the moment you're passing a single number to sum, which expects an iterable of numbers.

Comment: You probably want to calculate the average over the entire class, I assume. In that case, instead of `average = sum(student_info[student_name]/len(student_info))` you should do `average = sum(student_info.values())/len(student_info)`. The latter will return all the values of the dict as a `list`, which is a valid input to the `sum` function.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you've posted a question, you have licensed the content to the Stack Overflow community at large (under the CC-by-SA license).  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323395/what-is-the-proper-route-for-a-dissociation-request).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
sum(student_info.values())/len(student_info)
```